# java.sql.SQLException: No Data Access Object for AudienceManagerProfile - Tridion 2013

Tags: content-delivery, audience-manager

I am trying to configure Outbound Email in a Web Site running Tridion 2013. I have checked all the jar files and configuration files, they are correct, but still having the issue, if I try the same configuration files in a Tridion 2011 instance it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is in your cd_storage_conf.xml? I usually get this error when the DAO Bundle isn't configured.

Comment: I found the error, the cd_audiencemanager_conf present in the installer still have 6.0 as the version, I had to change it to 7.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

The cd_audiencemanager_conf.xml in the installer folder still has 6.0 as the version number, I had to change it to 7.0